# load template in emacs when creating new file

Tags: ruby, emacs

I have a template I use when creating a ruby script.

Currently when I rename a copy of that template and load it in emacs and get to coding.

I *think* emacs can load a template for me though.  Ideally I could do this.

- Ctrl X Ctrl F to open a file.
- Type in name of file that doesn't exist (aka my new file).
- Emacs recognizes the file doesn't exist and loads my template (right now it loads a blank screen).

Anyone done this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'maybe-load-template)
(defun maybe-load-template ()
  (interactive)
  (when (and 
         (string-match "\\.rb$" (buffer-file-name))
         (eq 1 (point-max)))
    (insert-file "C:/Home/template.rb")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like the ['template'](http://emacs-template.sourceforge.net/details.html) package. Or, alternatively, if you are comfortable with emacs-lisp to define the template you can use the built-in [skeleton](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode) functionality in emacs 22 and above.

Answer (score 2):

There are [lots](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders) of ways to do it on the Emacs wiki.